# PHP read data from several text files, outputting a certain line from all files?

Tags: php, file

I'm trying to write a script which reads the contents of 25 heavy text files (about 100 lines each). I want my script to output line 5 of each text file. I am also working on a windows workstation (using Apache in a local environment for testing).

Each text file is located in the same directory (i.e. products/product1.txt) which I guess makes it easier.

Each text file, on line 5, looks like this (with different descriptions):

```
Product Desc: iphone
```

I would also like to know if its possible, after achieving the above, to have the script remove the text 'Product Desc: ', so that only the actual product description is displayed.

Please provide any code examples as I am a noobie :)

Comment: Do you need to read all of the files in the directory? Or, more specifically, are there files in that directory that you do not want to read?

Comment: I do have an example which reads every file and all its contents, and thats it. Its a total mess however and is very 'PHP busy'. I'd hope a more experienced developer would come up with something more creative!

Comment: @Matthew, need to read all of the files in the directory. hope that helps? does this make it easier/more difficult?

Comment: It makes it a little simpler. You could further look at specific files within the directory (by extension, perhaps), but looping through the whole bit makes the code a little lighter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = opendir('directory');
while($file = readdir($dir)){
   if ($file != "." or $file != ".."){
      $opened = file($file);
      echo $opened[4]."<br />";
   }
}
```

Comment: is there a more efficient way? Say if the number of products continues to grow. i.e. we may have 100+ by Xmas :)

Comment: Uh you're missing loads of steps... `fopen` just returns a resource, no t the file content ;)

Comment: @genesis this looks perfect. excuse my stupidity, but could you include where I would call in the reference to the directory - I am an old school macro excel programmer :)

Comment: @JaneKealum: change `'file'.$i` to `'directory/file'.$i`

Comment: @genesis: looks promising, however I am receiving a blank output in my html page. also i wouldnt be poiting to a specific file in a directory surely? therefore would it be 'directory/*.txt'? I cant get this working either :(

Comment: @Jane What file you want exactly to get? directory/test1.txt, directory/test2.txt and so on?

Comment: Probably looking to something like `foreach (glob('dir/*.txt') as $file) { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: @genesis: I want to get line 5 from every file in a particular directory. There are currently 25 files in the directory, however this will most likely grow. so an array looking at all files in a certain directory would fit. thanks for the help.

Comment: Kudos for being really small, but it isn't very robust nor understandable to a new user.

Comment: @genesis: still not working on my end? I'm receiving a blank input on my page. seems like no files are being read, or the fifth line is not being stored?

Comment: @Levi Morrison: :) yeah unfortunately I am a newbie with PHP, I'm from a an excel macro background from the 90s haha

Comment: @JaneKealum I'd recommend that you take a look at my answer.  It's much more understandable because it's done from a well-structured approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180128/php-read-data-from-several-text-files-outputting-a-certain-line-from-all-files/7180760#7180760

Answer (score 0):

**PHP to load multiple files:**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Edmonton");
$products=array();
$dir="../products/"; //Set this for whatever your folder


function getProduct($file) {
    $fp=fopen($file,"r");
    //Read five lines
    for ($j=0;$j<5;$j++) $line=fgets($fp);
    $GLOBALS["products"][]=substr($line,14);//Since products is a global var
    fclose($fp);
}

$dp=opendir($dir);
while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== false) {
  if ($file!="." && $file!="..")
    getProduct($dir.$file);
}
closedir($dp);

//Review the product list
print_r($products);
?>
```

**An example file (one.txt):**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
Product Desc: iPhone
line 6
```

**Shortcuts:**

Because we only want the fifth line we use the `$j` loop to read the first five lines each overwriting the last.  If the file is less than five lines you'll get a `null` out of `$line`... you should test for that (and not add it to the product list).  Finally because we now the length of the string "`Product Desc:`" (the way you wrote it) we can just throw that first part of the line away.  This isn't terrible robust, better to use a RegEx, or string parsing to make sure the right words are there, and then consume the data following the colon.  Still... it answers your original question ;)

You said there could be many more lines, this approach only loads the first 5 lines into memory (each over writing the last) and stops once the fifth line is reached... which means serious performance and memory advantages over reading the whole file into an array (`file`) and then only using line 5.

**Design Decisions:**

It looks like you're building a product catalog, it would be much better to use a database to store this data.  Doesn't have to be a big deal (MySQL, PostgreSQL) it could be something as easy as SQLite.

Comment: thanks for the in-depth details and easy-to-understand description of $j which is new to me :) This works perfectly, however, could you edit the answer so that I do not have to specifically name each file in the directory? e.g. by Xmas we may have 100+ products! thanks again

Comment: hmm.. having issues now getting the array ti display anything. simpy getting a blank screen now. no inputs in the file are being seen? They were before your change however :S

Comment: i think im close, however im not having any values outputted? I am getting the list with the array seeing that there are 25 files. However, no string output for the value of the 5th line for each file. Could this be associated with the global var of 'products'? I didn't know this was the case...

Comment: @JaneKealum I guess I'd add some debugging: first line of `getProduct` add `echo "get $file<br />";` (which will show files are being read - should output 25 names).  After the `for` in that same function add `echo "$line<br />";` to see the line that's being captured.. if it's off (not the fifth?) adjust `$j` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So this is essentially three parts: (1) you need to loop through the directory, (2) reading in the fifth line of each file and (3) you need to read the section of that line, after the colon.

```
  // open the products directory  
  $fileHandle = opendir('products');

  // create an array to store the file data
  $files = array();

  // create an array to store products
  $products = array();

  if ($fileHandle) {
    // loop through each file
    while ( false !== ($singleFile = readdir($fileHandle)) ) {

      // use file() to read the lines of the file
      $lines = file($singleFile);

      // store the fifth line in each file (the array starts at 0)
      $productDescription = explode(":",$lines[4]);
      $products[] = productDescription[1]; // the bit after the colon
    }
  }

  // this should show you an array of the products
  print_r($products);
```

Comment: nice and clean, and i understand how it works here, although I think there may be a bug? I'm receiving a server 500 error now. I tried: opendir('products') and opendir('products/').

Comment: You can always run this code from within the products directory and use opendir(".")

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: http://pastebin.com/WBBQW9wA** *(raw code at bottom)*

**The process is three-fold.**

1. Get all the filenames in the directory.
2. Read in the fifth line each file.
3. Split after the colon.

**My method is very well documented and understandable.**  It uses functions to do specific parts of the process.  It's quite easy to understand what's going on, and is fairly robust at the same time.

---

Functions that do the work:

```
<?php
    function readAfterColon($string) {
    /**
     * @param string $string The string you'd like to split on.
     * 
     * @return string The data after the colon.  Multiple colons work just fine.
     */
    $array = explode(":",$string, 2);
    return isset($array[1]) ? $array[1] : '';
    }

    function readLine($lineNumber, $fileName) {
        /**
         * @param int $lineNumber The line number you want to read from the file.
         * @param string $fileName The string representing the file you wish to open.
         * 
         * @return string The contents of the line in the file.
         */
        $file = file($fileName);
        return $file[$lineNumber-1];
    }

    function readLineFrom($lineNumber, $fileNames) {
        /**
         * @param int $lineNumber The line number you want to read from the file.
         * @param string|array $files Either a string for the file you want to open, or an array of filenames.
         * 
         * @return array An associative array of the filename to the contents of the line.
         */
        $lines = array();
        if(is_array($fileNames)) {
            foreach($fileNames as $fileName) {
                $lines[$fileName] = readLine($lineNumber, $fileName);
            }
        } else {
            $lines[$fileNames] = readLine($lineNumber, $fileNames);
        }

        return $lines;
    }

    function getFileNamesFromDirectory($directory = '.') {
        /**
         * @param string $directory The path to directory you'd like to get filenames from. Defaults to current directory.
         * 
         * @return array An array of filenames.  Empty if there are no files.
         */
        $fileNames = array();
        if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    $fileNames[] = $directory . $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
        return $fileNames;
    }

?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
    //include the functions, then:
    //get the line from every file
    $descriptions = readLineFrom(5, getFileNamesFromDirectory('/var/www/test/'));

    //get the contents after the colon
    foreach($descriptions as $fileName=>$description) {
        $descriptions[$fileName] = readAfterColon($description);
    }

    //display it
    echo "<pre>\n";
    print_r($descriptions);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for in terms of explanation. This is much appreciated, Ive just spent 30 mins analyzing the code carefully tio get a better understanding of the syntax... Having problems however; script is correctly outputting filenames (all 25), however there is no value being displayed for the 5th line in each file? :(

Comment: Hmm. . . try printing out before the foreach loop and see if you have the raw data with the colon.  Perhaps I have a typo in my final code somewhere.

Comment: @JaneKealum I found the error, I had forgotten to include the directory path for the filename.  It works beautifully in all my tests, now.